# Histogram normalise figure output

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I have a big matrix with thousands of values. I want to make a histogram of each signal. This is easily done with MALTAB's commands. My problem is I want it normalised in the sense that the y-axis is 0-1 and not 0-(the number of measurements). Any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use histc()

```
counts = histc(data);
normCounts = counts/sum(counts);
```